# Trying to display a H264 video out of the browser space using mpv

Tags: qt, web, hardware-acceleration, window-managers, mpv

I'm currently working on a QT browser using MPV to display videos. For personnal matters I need to display a video outside of the surface allowed by the browser page. So the video needs to be cut by the bottom of the page. For some reasons the video is pushed up by the hardware video acceleration.

I tried to launch the video with the mpv command:

```
DISPLAY=:0 mpv --vo vaapi --vd-lavc-o=threads=1 --sws-scaler=fast-bilinear --vd-lavc-threads=1 --vd-lavc-fast=yes --cache=no --cache-backbuffer=0 --cache-default=no --cache-initial=0 --cache-secs=0 --really-quiet --no-input-default-bindings --demuxer-lavf-probesize=512000 --a60hz src19.sdp,src20.sdp,src21.sdp,src22.sdp,src23.sdp,src24.sdp,src26.sdp,src27.sdp,src28.sdp,src29.sdp,src30.sdp,src31.sdp,src32.sdp,src33.sdp --aspect 5:4 --geometry 720x576+240+1100 /tmp/mpv-sdp/src03.sdp
```

The geometry parameter defines the widht x height + posX + posY.
The video is being displayed on the browser but the posY or posX of the video seems to be pushed to fit in the display.

Here's the logs of the command:

```
start measure_main
Feature above-60Hz : AUTO DETECTION
Nom SDP : src05.sdp =?= src19.sdp?
Nom SDP : src05.sdp =?= src20.sdp?
Nom SDP : src05.sdp =?= src21.sdp?
Nom SDP : src05.sdp =?= src22.sdp?
Nom SDP : src05.sdp =?= src23.sdp?
Nom SDP : src05.sdp =?= src24.sdp?
Nom SDP : src05.sdp =?= src26.sdp?
Nom SDP : src05.sdp =?= src27.sdp?
Nom SDP : src05.sdp =?= src28.sdp?
Nom SDP : src05.sdp =?= src29.sdp?
Nom SDP : src05.sdp =?= src30.sdp?
Nom SDP : src05.sdp =?= src31.sdp?
Nom SDP : src05.sdp =?= src32.sdp?
Nom SDP : src05.sdp =?= src33.sdp?
start measure
avformat_open_input
avformat_find_stream_info 0
add_new_streams
demux_get_num_stream
Measure : 0 / 0 / 90000 (1000000)
TEMPS DEMARRAGE depuis MAIN : 0.090000 s (time used)
TEMPS DEMARRAGE depuis demux_open() : 0.090000 s (time used)
TEMPS DEMARRAGE depuis MAIN : 1.000000 s (wallclock time)
TEMPS DEMARRAGE depuis demux_open() : 1.000000 s (wallclock time)
vdpau_video: VdpPresentationQueueBlockUntilSurfaceIdle(): status 2: The display was pre-empted, or a fatal error occurred.
vdpau_video: VdpPresentationQueueBlockUntilSurfaceIdle(): status 3: An invalid handle value was provided.
vdpau_video: VdpPresentationQueueBlockUntilSurfaceIdle(): status 3: An invalid handle value was provided.
vdpau_video: VdpPresentationQueueBlockUntilSurfaceIdle(): status 3: An invalid handle value was provided.
vdpau_video: VdpPresentationQueueBlockUntilSurfaceIdle(): status 3: An invalid handle value was provided.
```

I have 2 different clients, both with centOS 7. One is working fine but the other doesn't accept the video to be cut off.
The main differences between those 2 is the window manager and the GPU:
- Compiz with intel GPU works fine
- Metacity with Nvidia GPU doesnt work

What could be the issue causing vdpau_video to report an error and to push the video out of the geometry called?

Comment: Just FYI, using ``` <code> ``` will put all of your block of log/code/whatever in a readable format instead of wrapping each line with single ` <code> `.